# Why jqGrid is very slow in ipad?

Tags: ipad, jqgrid, scroll, jqgrid-php

I have a jqgrid with more than thousands of data. In pad there is not smooth scrolling of grid rows. (I am using Ace Admin theme) Do anybody know any solutions. thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the code which you use? Do you use paging (local or server side) of data?

Comment: it loads server side of data.

Comment: My question was about **paging** of data. I asked you to append the text of your question with **the JavaScript code** which you used to create the jqGrid.